# Doing set intersection between input array and column of arrays in collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I have an array that a user will input that I want to check against every document in the collection. Every document has a column named "members" that has its own array. I'd like for mongo to loop through every column and do a setIntersection to see how similar the 2 arrays are, and return the result to  me so I can show the user which documents are closest to their input. As of now in pymongo, I have gotten up to this command before I hit a roadblock.

```
list(collection.aggregate([{"$project":{"members":1,'id':1}},
{"$match":{"members":["FOXF1","GATA6","SOX9","TWIST1","ZEB1","ZEB2"]}}]))
```

This command goes through the members column of every document and returns to me the id and members of any exact matches to the query :

```
"members":["FOXF1","GATA6","SOX9","TWIST1","ZEB1","ZEB2"]
```

I'd like to take this a step further but I am not sure how I can begin tackling not only doing a setIntersection, but having it done on every document at once.

The documentation shows a simple example comparing 2 arrays

```
commonToBoth: { db.experiments.aggregate([
{ $project: { A: 1, B: 1, commonToBoth: { $setIntersection: [ "$A", "$B" ] }, _id: 0 } }])
```

I'd like the 2nd array to be looped through every document's members column. So I can have the setIntersection done for all documents all at once, I'm not really sure where to begin.

Another thing I'm unsure of pymongo's syntax for **setIntersection**. As an example, mongo uses **findOne** while pymongo uses `find_one`. I found this not to be the case for setIntersection. Neither `$set_intersection` nor `$setIntersection` work and I have not found any documentation online for how to do set intersection in pymongo. Thanks for reading and for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

```
inputArray = ["FOXF1", "GATA6", "SOX9", "TWIST1", "ZEB1", "ZEB2"]

list(collection.aggregate([{ "$match": { "members": { $in: inputArray } } },
{
    $project: {
        matchingCount: { $size: { $setIntersection: ['$members', inputArray] } }
        , matchingMembers: { $setIntersection: ['$members', inputArray] }
    }
}, { $sort: { 'matchingCount': -1 } }]))
```

If in case you've an `id` field then you can do `id : 1` & `_id : 0` in `$project`. Since you've a `$match` this output will only contain documents having at least one matching element from inputArray to members array, if you want to check match ratio across all documents in collection then simply remove that filter, but it would be good to have match as first stage as DB operation is much optimized by reducing total no.of documents for later stages.

**Sample Documents :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd859f93d319574a17e9be9"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA6", 
        "SOX9", 
        "TWIST1", 
        "ZEB1", 
        "ZEB2"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a053d319574a17e9e0c"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF11", 
        "GATA61", 
        "SOX91", 
        "TWIST11", 
        "ZEB11", 
        "ZEB21"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a0f3d319574a17ea02a"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF1"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a1a3d319574a17ea29d"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "ZEB2"
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a263d319574a17ea4fa"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA61", 
        "SOX91", 
        "TWIST11", 
        "ZEB1", 
        "ZEB2"
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a343d319574a17ea79c"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA6", 
        "SOX9"
    ]
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a433d319574a17eaa4b"),
    "members" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA6", 
        "SOX9", 
        "TWIST1"
    ]
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a4d3d319574a17eab7a"),
    "members" : []
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a573d319574a17eac89"),
    "members1" : ""
}
```

**Output :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd859f93d319574a17e9be9"),
    "matchingCount" : 6,
    "matchingMembers" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA6", 
        "SOX9", 
        "TWIST1", 
        "ZEB1", 
        "ZEB2"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a433d319574a17eaa4b"),
    "matchingCount" : 4,
    "matchingMembers" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA6", 
        "SOX9", 
        "TWIST1"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a263d319574a17ea4fa"),
    "matchingCount" : 3,
    "matchingMembers" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "ZEB1", 
        "ZEB2"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a343d319574a17ea79c"),
    "matchingCount" : 3,
    "matchingMembers" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "GATA6", 
        "SOX9"
    ]
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a1a3d319574a17ea29d"),
    "matchingCount" : 2,
    "matchingMembers" : [ 
        "FOXF1", 
        "ZEB2"
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd85a0f3d319574a17ea02a"),
    "matchingCount" : 1,
    "matchingMembers" : [ 
        "FOXF1"
    ]
}
```

Comment: That query did the trick perfectly and exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much.